# Mouse Click event

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am using RCP with eclipse 3.6 and java 6.

The user needs to click with right mouse buttom then opened a menu where he makes a choice.
Which mouse event is that?
How to fill the menu with choices?.

Regards,
Haythem

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article [about RCP and eclipse 3.6](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html#contextmenu). The section that I've linked to describes how to create a context menu (for a table), that will pop up when right clicking.

Comment: He is talking of `eclipse-rcp` and `swt\jface`. And not about `Swing`.

Answer (score 0):

What I need is how to create mouseeventlistener from a menu and menuitem 
Sectionstop in my code is the composite where the mouselistener will be added

```
Menu menu = new Menu (parent.getShell(), SWT.POP_UP);
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
        item.setText("Text 1");
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
        item2.setText("text 2");
        sectionStop.setMenu (menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on your RCP, the basic question is where does the user right clicks. Is it on your view/editor or on an object that you contributed to some viewers? A better If you then you should look into contributing via the proper extension points. Either org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus or org.eclipse.ui.menus with locationURI "popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any"

Comment: The user will right click on the view or on a table. 
How to tell the listener, now is text 1 selected do same thing?

Comment: your table should be set as the selectionprovider of the viewsite. Then in your handler, you can look for the current selection variable (use HandlerUtil class)